# Alias for a table of type?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following definition for a table type

```
create table number_table as table of number;
```

And I'd like to use it like in the following example.

```
declare
  l_myTable number_table := number_table(1, 2, 3);
begin
  for i in (select * from l_myTable) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.???); -- how do I reference the numbers here?
  end loop;
end;
```

Forgive my code being somewhat pointless, how would I reference that `i.???` though to get the number out of the iterator?

Comment: Did you mean `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE TYPE`? I'm assuming the later as the former is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slightly change your query to

```
select rownum, column_value from l_myTable
```

and then use `dbms_output.put_line(i.rownum);` as an index and `dbms_output.put_line(i.column_value );` as a value

Answer (score 0):

```
create type number_table as table of number;
/
```

You do not need to use a [Cursor FOR LOOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155) as you can just iterate over the collection:

```
declare
  l_myTable number_table := number_table(3, 2, 1);
begin
  for i in 1 .. l_myTable.COUNT loop
    dbms_output.put_line( l_myTable(i) );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

However, if there is some reason why you need to use a cursor then you can use the [`ROWNUM` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) to get index within the collection and the [`COLUMN_VALUE` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns004.htm) to get the value at that index in the collection using the query:

```
SELECT ROWNUM, COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( l_myTable )
```

Like this:

```
declare
  l_myTable number_table := number_table(3, 2, 1);
begin
  for i in ( SELECT ROWNUM, COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( l_myTable ) ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line( i.rownum || ': ' || i.column_value ); -- how do I reference the numbers here?
  end loop;
end;
/
```